# is there any way to avoid JSONObject from putting escape char?

Tags: java, jquery, getjson

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put(BEAN, jsonUtility.getJSONFromObject(bean));
```

this results

```
{"resp1":"{\"resp2\":\"TQ\",\"resp3\":\"2016-05-31\",\"resp4\":0}"}
{"resp1":"{"resp2":"TQ","resp3":"2016-05-31","resp4":0}"}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript... or jQuery... what is this?

Comment: Looks like Java code with beans.

Comment: yes its java i missed to add